# Prometheus Python see current value of metric

Tags: python, prometheus

From the prometheus python documentation, let's say I run this:

```
from prometheus_client import Counter
c = Counter('my_failures', 'Description of counter')
c.inc()     # Increment by 1
c.inc(1.6)  # Increment by given value
```

How might I get the value of the `c` metric after performing both of these increments? This is for testing purposes, I want to be able to test

```
c.value == 2.6
```

Except I can't seem to find a value accessor.

Is this even possible, or should I find another way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [source code](https://github.com/prometheus/client_python/blob/057b95d8471105b648d47fc304bd6c118f2722ab/prometheus_client/metrics.py#L215), it looks like you can access it by `_value` attribute:

```py
c._value.get() == 2.6
```